# Why does not acceleration affect time dilation in addition to the time dilation caused by velocity?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, acceleration, time-dilation

In his book, [*Relativity: The Special and General Theory*](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/5001/5001-h/5001-h.htm#xd29e3459), Einstein claimed that the clocks located on a rotating disc run slower solely due to their tangential velocities as appear in the Lorentz factor, no matter how much acceleration they take. He then replaces *potential per unit mass* with *velocity square* $(r^2\omega^2)$:

> If we represent the difference of potential of the centrifugal force between the position of the clock and the centre of the disc by $\phi$ , i.e. the work, considered negatively, which must be performed on the unit of mass against the centrifugal force in order to transport it from the position of the clock on the rotating disc to the centre of the disc, then we have
>
> $$\phi=\frac{\omega^2r^2}{2}$$

However, I cannot really understand why the centrifugal acceleration does not affect clocks at all. Assume we have two concentric rings one with a large radius and the other with a very small one. If the rings rotate at the same tangential velocity, according to Einstein, the clocks run slower at the same rate as measured by an inertial observer at rest with respect to the plate's center. However, according to the centrifugal acceleration formula:

$$a=\frac{v^2}{r}\space,$$

the clock on the ring with a smaller radius experiences much more acceleration than one located on that with a larger radius. How can it be possible that such a large centrifugal force/acceleration, which can easily mash the nearer clock to the center of rotation (if the radius is small enough), is ineffective in altering time rates? (Forget about the viewpoint of the rotating observers.)

Remember that if the radius approaches zero, the centrifugal acceleration tends to infinity, yet the tangential velocity can remain unchanged. It is really hard for me to understand why an infinite acceleration/force cannot affect clock rates!

Comment: Have you tried just calculating the time dilation factor and seeing what happens?

Comment: Yes, the time dilation factor just depends on velocity rather than acceleration.

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry Well then, there you have it - the time dilation is different because the velocity is different. Are you looking instead for an explanation why time dilation depends on velocity and not acceleration?

Comment: @probably_someone Yes. It is slightly awkward to me why the acceleration has no place in the Lorentz factor at least for when an inertial observer investigates the behavior of accelerated objects.

Comment: It seems to me that you're asking "why doesn't acceleration affect time dilation in addition to the time dilation caused by velocity?". Is that correct?

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry The acceleration has a place in the Lorentz factor in that it changes the velocity of objects.

Comment: @PM 2Ring It's exactly correct.

Comment: @probably_someone You are correct in general. But your deduction does not work for the rotating rings explained in my question.

Comment: @PM 2Ring I've changed the question title to your suggested one. Thanks!

Comment: Why would we think that time dilation should depend on acceleration? You mention that a clock could be mashed, but ordinary time dilation doesn't mash clocks, so why is that relevant?

Comment: @Dale I was speaking figuratively. I meant that if extreme accelerations are capable of crumpling the clocks, why cannot they affect time rates? To me, it is clear that biological clocks are very sensitive to high accelerations. Why do you think that it is unlikely that the same happens for physical clocks?

Comment: That is just it. Extreme velocity is not capable of crumpling clocks, but it causes time dilation. Extreme velocity does not mash or crumple or affect clocks other than time dilation. And the effect of velocity is the same for all clocks. Acceleration crumples mashes and otherwise affects clocks, and it does so very differently for different clocks. Nothing in that is similar to velocity time dilation. The very “sensitivity” you mentioned is a dissimilarity between velocity and acceleration

Comment: @Dale As I noted in my comments below, an effective length of the clock/observer, as well as its acceleration, can determine the time dilation due to the acceleration. Yes, it can be different for different clocks. It is not necessary for acceleration to dilate time the same as velocity does because of their different natures. If pendulum clocks are sensitive to acceleration, my heart (as a clock) is sensitive to my velocity when I run at a uniform speed. Cars' wheels (as clocks) have also velocity-dependent rates. So what?!

Comment: You said “Yes, it can be different for different clocks”, but then it wouldn’t be time dilation. Whatever time dilation is it must affect all clocks identically for it to be attributed to time rather than to the clock. You also said “my heart (as a clock) is sensitive to my velocity when I run at a uniform speed”, no it isn’t. You can run on a treadmill, or on the ground, or in a relativistic rocket, your heart is not sensitive to your speed other than time dilation, and even then by the exact same amount as a light clock. Anyway, I am just saying your question seems incorrectly motivated

Comment: It looks like we have exceeded the “extended discussion” limit. You have a bunch of good answers, so I will just bow out of this. I just don’t think that the reasons you mention for motivating why there should be acceleration time dilation are valid. They all seem to be differences from velocity, not similarities

Answer (score 3):

Your question has the same ring as, say, the following question:

"We know that everything slows down and stops, unless you keep pushing. Push an object across the floor, it keeps moving. Stop pushing: it stops. It is really hard for me to understand how satelites in orbit keep moving without anything pushing them around."

In your case what you are stuck on is a wrong assumption (a wrong assumption about time dilation.)

I do grant you that your wrong assumption is very tempting. Many go down that road.

To address the wrong assumption let me take the Twin scenario as example.

As is often done, I will call them Alice and Bob.
Alice goes on a journey, Bob stays put.
Alice makes her far away U-turn, and when Alice and Bob rejoin the amount of elapsed proper time for Alice is less than the amount of elapsed proper time for Bob.

Both Alice and Bob are scientists with full understanding of time dilation, so given the travel plan they know in advance how large the difference in elapsed proper time will be.

The way to calculate the difference in amount of elapsed proper time is to apply the [Minkowski metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space). Bob has traveled forward in time along the shortest path; he hasn't moved. Alice has not taken the shortest path: in addition to travelling forward in time she has traveled spatial distance. To calculate the difference in elapsed proper time you evaluate one thing and one thing only: the difference in spatial distance traveled.

The *shape* of the journey that Alice made does not matter. Several other siblings can make all kinds of journeys, if all those journeys are in the end the same spatial distance (compared to each other) then for all those travellers the same amount of proper time will have elapsed.

The fact that the *shape* of the journey doesn't matter follows from this: as you evaluate the total spatial distance traveled (applying the Minkowski metric) the *shape* of the journey drops out of the calculation.

Of course, the acceleration is necessary; Alice has to make that U-turn, that's the only way to rejoin Bob. But whether the U-turn is sharp (pulling a lot of G's) or gradual (low G-load), that doesn't matter. The journey that Alice makes can be a zigzag course, pulling G's all the time; it doesn't matter, only the difference in spatial distance travelled counts.

Yes, that is very counter-intuitive.
Superficially you might expect that the difference in spatial distance travelled is irrelevant, it looks so passive.
By contrast, the *acceleration* is violent, surely that's where it happens.

In actual fact the difference of elapsed proper time is described by the Minkowski metric. The Minkowski metric is necessary, and sufficient.

To learn the logical implications of the Minkowski metric is to learn Special Relativity.

Comment: Repeating the twin paradox scenario cannot provide me with a clear answer to my question. Why this **very counter-intuitive** phenomenon (as mentioned by you) is assumed to be a good description of nature?

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry Because we have observed its effects everywhere, and never once have we observed anything counter to its predictions. One of the most famous examples is the fact that we see muons in particle detectors at Earth's surface. Muons have a lifetime of 2 microseconds, which means it would naively be expected to travel around $c\times 2\times 10^{-6}\approx 300$ meters before decaying (we've also never seen faster-than-light muons). They're produced at the top of the atmosphere, tens of kilometers up, so the fact that we see them at sea level is because of time dilation.

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry We've also been able to **directly measure** time dilation in the same setup as in the twin paradox - see e.g. https://www.nist.gov/news-events/news/2010/09/nist-pair-aluminum-atomic-clocks-reveal-einsteins-relativity-personal-scale. In particular, NIST assembled two atomic clocks: one was a reference and the other was made to oscillate back and forth, regularly performing the "twin paradox" journey. The oscillating clock ticked slightly slower than the stationary clock.

Comment: @probably_someone Muon decay does not relate to the rotating disc. I am not questioning special relativity for inertial frames, but rather I am confused about applying SR to accelerated objects as measured by inertial observers. Moreover, every precise experiment is performed within an error range. It is possible that a novel theory or an alternative to SR that corrects SR deficiencies falls within the obtained error range too. Besides, I am really doubtful if there has been carried out any experiment in *high centrifugal accelerations* showing that relativity is not flawed in this case.

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry Time dilation can be very important in particle accelerator experiments, where the rest frame half-life of reaction products can be *much* smaller than the muon half-life. If centripetal acceleration affected time dilation then it would have been noticed in experiments at the LHC and other circular accelerators.

Comment: @PM 2Ring This is possibly due to the fact that we do not exactly know how acceleration affects our equations. It is also possible that something like the *internal pressure* affects the equation of time dilation rather than the acceleration itself. For fundamental particles, this *pressure* can be negligible even in high centrifugal accelerations. Moreover, in accelerators with great radii (many Kilometers), it is possible that the centrifugal accelerations are not great enough.

Comment: @Mohammad Javanshiry Not great enough? The LHC has a circumference of 27 km. Particles in the ring travel at almost lightspeed. Using $a_c = v^2/r$ gives a centripetal acceleration of $2\times 10^{13} m/s^2$. That should be big enough to notice an effect. ;)

Comment: @PM 2Ring What if the acceleration effect appears as the term $(ad/c^2)^2$, where $a$ is the centrifugal acceleration, and $d$ is the diameter of the particle? ;)

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry 1) Particles don't all have a nonzero diameter. For instance, everything we measure about leptons is consistent with them being point particles (i.e. having zero diameter). 2) If you can come up with a framework surrounding that "acceleration effect" that both explains all previous experimental data _and_ predicts future results _better than_ special relativity, congratulations on your Nobel Prize. Until then, we have absolutely no reason to believe that such an effect exists. Conclusions in science require the support of experimental evidence.

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry Regarding centripetal acceleration, we have tested to much higher accelerations than the LHC, in the early days of accelerator physics. For example, the Cambridge Electron Accelerator was 236 ft (72 m) in diameter and accelerated electrons ($m=511$ keV) to an energy of 6 GeV, which puts them at a velocity of $0.99995c$, making for a centripetal acceleration of $1.2\times 10^{15}$ m/s$^{2}$. But probably whatever number I give you, your response will be "yeah, but what if it's higher than that?", which is why I say: give us a reason to test that hypothesis (i.e. see above).

Comment: @probably_someone The best thing that can encourage you to take my question seriously is *logic* $-$ a *physical logic* indeed $-$ which is superior to any experiment, unless you want to shrink from any logical reasoning which is in vogue nowadays!

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry Logical reasoning must rest on axioms. Not all sets of axioms are equally good at describing nature (for example, the axiom "The speed of light is $c$ in _every_ reference frame" which underpins relativity is supported by every experiment we've made so far, while the axiom "The speed of light is $c$ in _one particular_ reference frame" is not). A perfect logical argument founded on axioms that don't describe nature makes conclusions that have no connection to an accurate description of nature. What are the axioms of the framework that leads to your alteration?

Comment: @probably_someone My axiom: Time cannot be dilated similarly for both clocks one in low centrifugal accelerations and the other one under extremely high accelerations as measured by a specific inertial observer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100896/discussion-between-probably-someone-and-mohammad-javanshiry).

Comment: I understand what you say about the metric and how the time dilation effect is only due to the distance travelled and not the path taken. But this seems to contradict the equivalence principle? We are told that gravitational fields also cause time dilation effects, so why not acceleration? If gravity causes time dilation but acceleration does not, then the equivalence principle goes out the window?

Comment: You're right that "the difference of elapsed proper time is described by the Minkowski metric" but you contradict this when you say that "the difference in elapsed proper time [is all about] the difference in spatial distance traveled." The metric gives distance in space***time***, not just in space. Because of this, speeds (and the time spent at those speeds) have to be factored in as well, not just spatial distances.

Answer (score 1):

I would not expect centripetal acceleration to have any effect. The motivation for SR was the principle that the speed of light should be the same for all observers. The Lorentz transform explains how one can account for the effects of relative motion between observers, ie the speed and direction of the motion. Acceleration is simply a change either in the speed or the direction of a motion, so it simply requires you to plug different values into the transformation equations. At any instant an accelerating body has a definite speed and a definite direction to its motion, so at that instant the Lorentz transform adequately quantifies all relativistic effects. The magnitude of those effects changes from instant to instant as the velocity of the body changes, but we have no reason to suppose that the nature of the effects would change.

Comment: Then do you mean that even at infinite accelerations, the clocks easily comply with Lorentz transformation, whereas defining a *clock* at infinite accelerations can even be impossible?! (as a matter of logic)

Comment: Hi Mohammad, I wouldn't like to guess what would happen at an infinite acceleration. Out of interest, why do you say that defining a clock is impossible under those circumstances?

Comment: Hello Marco, I think even if it is possible to define a clock, it is absurd $-$ to me $-$ if this infinite acceleration does not affect the clock (time rate, that is.).

Comment: Hi Mohammed. I'm interested in knowing why you think it would have an effect, so please share your thoughts on that. In particular, do you imagine that the effect would be proportional to the magnitude of the acceleration? If so, what might the constant of proportionality be?

Comment: I am afraid that I cannot present my thoughts in detail because, first, I have not reached a certain deduction on it yet, and second, I am trying to write an article about it. However, my initial calculations show that there can be proportionality to acceleration.

Comment: My calculation shows that a term $\frac{a^{3/2}\sqrt{d}}{c^2\omega}$, as well as the clock's tangential velocity, can play a decisive role in time dilation for accelerated particles, where $a$ is the centrifugal acceleration, $\omega$ is the angular velocity, and $d$ is the effective length of the rotating clock. I am not so sure about the mentioned term because I am still working on it.

Answer (score 0):

for a rotate coordinate system with the constant angular velocity $\omega$   the coordinates are:

$$x=x'\cos(\omega\,t')-y'\sin(\omega\,t')$$
$$y=x'\sin(\omega\,t')+y'\cos(\omega\,t')$$
$$z=z'$$
$$t=t'$$

with $ds^2=\eta_{\mu\nu}\,dx^\mu\,dx^\nu=c^2\,dt^2-dx^2-dy^2-dz^2$

we get the metric

$$G=\left[ \begin {array}{cccc}  \left( -{x'}^{2}-{y'}^{2} \right) {\omega}
^{2}+{c}^{2}&\omega\,y'&-\omega\,x'&0\\ \omega\,y'&-1&0
&0\\-\omega\,x'&0&-1&0\\ 0&0&0&-1
\end {array} \right] 
$$

with:

$dx'=dy'=dz'=0$ we get

$$d\tau=\frac{ds_{\text{clock}}}{c}=\sqrt{G_{00}}\,dt'=
\sqrt{1-\frac{\omega^2\,(x'^2+y'^2)}{c^2}}\,dt'$$

so $d\tau$ is a function of the clock distance from the center $x'^2+y'^2=r^2$ and the angular velocity. with $\omega=\frac{v}{r}=\frac{v}{\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}}$ we get for $d\tau$

$$d\tau=\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}\,dt'$$

Comment: As you see, there is no place for acceleration in the time dilation formula!

Comment: But $\omega ^{2}\cdot r^{2}=\left( \omega ^{2}\cdot r\right) \cdot r$ so you have the zentrifugal force in this equation?

Comment: It's not important how you rewrite velocity as a function of acceleration. In any form, there is no pure dependence of time dilation on acceleration, and it is velocity that plays a decisive role.

Comment: I know this but the acceleration is canceled the force per mass is still there

Comment: I edited your answer two hours ago, you had made a mistake in the last equation. Have you seen my edit?

Comment: Yes  Thank you my mistake

Comment: Have you been convinced that acceleration has no *direct* effect on time dilation?

Answer (score 0):

In **special relativity** time dilation is not affected by body's acceleration, however in **general relativity** - it is, because of [equivalence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle) (accelerating reference frame is indistinguishable from non-accelerating frame in gravity field). [Gravitational time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation#Outside_a_non-rotating_sphere) is defined through Schwarzschild metrics:

$$ t_{0}=t_{f}{\sqrt {1-{\frac {2GM}{rc^{2}}}}} $$

Using Newton's gravitation and second laws, one can re-write equation above as :

$$ t_0 =t_f\sqrt{1-2\frac{GMmr}{r^2c^2m}}
\\=t_f\sqrt{1-2\frac{F_{_G}r}{mc^2}}
\\=t_f\sqrt{1-2a\frac{r}{c^2}}
\\ =t_f\sqrt{1 - \frac{a}{a_s}} 
$$

where $a_s$ is *Schwarzschild acceleration* and is defined as :

$$ a_s = \frac{c^2}{2r} $$

Comment: Potential per unit mass or $2GM/r$ has a velocity square dimension. It is not important how you rewrite equations as a function of acceleration. Moreover, according to my own example of the rotating rings, it is evident that velocity determines the time dilation as mentioned by Einstein himself.

Comment: Einstein also introduced equivalence principle which you completely ignore here

Comment: My example has nothing to do with EEP; it is clear, and Einstein's position towards it is clear too.

Comment: Seems you don't get it. If equivalence principle is right, then time dilation experienced near massive objects (like black hole) should be the same experienced by objects simply moving at extra-ordinary accelerations. Otherwise Einstein's EP has no point and/or is **faulty**

Comment: Please focus on my example and show me how acceleration is inserted into the time dilation equation from the viewpoint of the inertial observer at rest WRT the rings.

Comment: It is not "inserted", it is derived from Newton laws of gravity and second law. Showed deriving details. And you focus on EP faultiness if acceleration not induces time dilation !

Answer (score 0):

In Special Relativity, it is assumed that *only* relative velocity has an effect on the *ideal*-clock rate, as read from another inertial observer.  It is implicitely postulated that the clock's acceleration has no effect, or else you would need some ***universal acceleration*** to compare, like there's an universal constant $c$ to compare velocities.  On dimensional grounds, you would need to introduce some acceleration parameter $g$ of some sort into the Lorentz transformation, a kind of universal constant (the *maximal* or *minimal* acceleration available in the universe?).

It is assumed that this $g = 0$ in SR.

In the past, some authors have already created extended theories which go above SR, but empirical data have ruled out most of these theories.  For example, you may be interested in *doubly special relativity*:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_special_relativity

From dimensional analysis, these theories could introduce some acceleration constant that could have an effect on clock rates.

Comment: Defining a universal acceleration is not necessary. My calculation shows that a term $\frac{a^{3/2}\sqrt{d}}{c^2\omega}$, as well as the clock's tangential velocity, can play a decisive role in time dilation for accelerated particles, where $a$ is the centrifugal acceleration, $\omega$ is the angular velocity, and $d$ is the effective length of the rotating clock. I am not so sure about the mentioned term because I am still working on it.

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry, if such an effect would have been there, don't you think that it would have already been noticed or found before, by the thousands of physicists and mathematicians that worked hard on SR since it was created by Einstein?  There is none!  So you're making a mistake in your analysis.

Comment: *don't you think that it would have already been noticed or found before* No, I do not. Because proving such an effect is not that easy. It needs the definition of *observer* to be revisited fundamentally. You have to know about *equal observers*, which has a long story behind it, to make a step forward. It is unlikely that anyone has heard the story before!

Comment: I just thought that "cats" can better understand "lion kids", but it seems that I was wrong ;)